# how to set the jpeg extension after get the current time and date to a variable?

Tags: php, image-uploading

I am uploading an image to a folder name "upload". Then I am changing the name and extension of the image. I am getting the current time and date with default time zone
now I am trying to set the image extension to "jpeg" after the getted date and time I was
tried but is not given result  I put my code here

I suppose when I upload image at that time my file name is "NEWYORK.JPG"  But after
upload the image I want to change the file name is "9/10/2012/05:31:15.jpeg" from
get the current time and date set default time zone.

> ```
> date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
> $imagename = date('d/m/Y-h:i:s', time());
> $imagename=basename($imagename,".jpg");
> echo $filename = $imagename;
> $upload   = $_FILES['ctgimage'];
> $target_path = "upload/";
>
>  echo $target_path .= $filename . "." . path_info($upload["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
>   if(move_uploaded_file($upload["tmp_name"],$target_path))
>   {
>           echo "uploaded successfully";           $cname=$_POST['ctgname'];
>           mysql_query("insert into category(ctg_name,ctgimage) 
>                values('$cname','$target_path')");
>
>   }
> ```

Comment: i think it is not working with this, try to make it unix timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Errors

- It should be `pathinfo` not `path_info`
- Use a valid File name like `d-m-Y` for folder `h.i.s` for file
- Too many Duplication
- Avoid SQL Injection by escaping

Example :

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

$target_path = "upload/";
$imageDir = date('d-m-Y', time());
$imageName = date('h.i.s', time());

$upload = $_FILES['ctgimage'];
$uploadExtention = pathinfo($upload["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if (! is_dir($target_path . "/" . $imageDir)) {
    mkdir($target_path . "/" . $imageDir);
}

$target_path = "$target_path/$imageDir/$imageName.$uploadExtention";
$cname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ctgname']);

if (move_uploaded_file($upload["tmp_name"], $target_path)) {
    echo "uploaded successfully";

    mysql_query("insert into category(ctg_name,ctgimage)
    values('$cname','$target_path')");
}
```

PHP DOC on `mysql_*****`

> Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:

Comment: i try this code both category name and image name is store in database but image is not upload

Comment: hey i solved problem i was not put the upload/ before image name

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest that you name your file with the UNIX timestamp, not the date.
Moreover, I'm not sure OS allows that filenames contains chars like "/"

Comment: yes you are right but now i am remove the slashes and upload the image and mysql get the name thanks for this advice i was forget this but you remember me thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to name the file `9/10/2012/05:31:15.jpeg` as PHP will interpret the slashes as folder directories when you try to save.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: yes you are right now i am remove the slash and just except the dateandtime without slash or any special character thankyou you are right

Answer (score 0):

The target directory must exist.

Also; only as a suggestion: Use Y/m/d/... Making the folder structure a bit nicer to sort/traverse/keep order.

```
├── 2011
│   └── 12
│       ├── 03/
│       ├── 07/
│       ├── 13/
│       ├── 16/
│       └── 24/
└── 2012
    ├── 02
    │   ├── 14/
    │   └── 20/
    └── 05
        └── 13/
```

And/or. i.e.

```
2012-03-11_13.26.13.jpeg  
2012-03-11_14.26.13.jpeg  
2012-07-14_13.26.13.jpeg
```

Instead of:

```
13-11-2012_13.26.13.jpeg  
14-07-2012_13.26.13.jpeg  
14-11-2012_14.26.13.jpeg
```

You would also need to append a unique string if two images has same time - else `move_uploaded_file()` overwrite target-file if it exists.

Also as mentioned, you can't have forwards slash in filename. I interpreted this as being part of a folder structure. If you want to fake it you can use Unicode 0x206F "⁄" - but not recommended.